# In VSCode-->settings.json, a particular line appears dimmer than the rest of the code. What is that indicating?

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, standards, stylelint

In VSCode, in settings.json for one of my extensions is a line

`"extends": "C:/Users/snarl/.vscode/extensions/stylelint-config-wordpress",`

But that line is dimmed compared to the rest of the text in the file, as if disabled, or path not found ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugT6Z.jpg)).  Is that indicating some kind of error I need to resolve?  That folder does indeed exist at that location ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMEhI.jpg)).

**Motivation For My Question**

I ask because this is a line of code I manually added to settings.json, as part of installation instructions for a particular extension.  I'm currently using the [stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint) extension to help notify me of errors while I type.  I am now trying to install a separate extension--[stylelint-config-wordpress](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/stylelint-config-wordpress)--which is a set of rules to be used with stylelint.  But that new ruleset doesn't seem to be working properly.  So I am now trying to troubleshoot why the new rules are not working properly. The settings.json file I edited is part of the stylelint-config-wordpress extension.

**Of Note**

- I am running Windows 10.
- When I initially installed stylelint, I installed it globally.  I can confirm it was installed properly and linting errors in my code, as expected.
- In the GitHub repo for stylelint-config-wordpress, there is one issue related to this ([see here](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/stylelint-config-wordpress/issues/216)).  I posted there and received some initial replies.  But nothing worked, and I've not heard back since.

Comment: that property is not recognized in any extension or VSC

Comment: @rioV8 OK interesting.  The 'Usage' section of the GitHub page (https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/stylelint-config-wordpress) indicates that I should add this line to my `styleline` settings.

Comment: you need to change the config file of this stylelint module

Comment: OK I'm up for doing that.  But can you clarify your suggestion?  Are you saying I need to edit settings.json for `stylelint-config-wordpress`?  If so, how exactly should I edit that file?

Comment: @rioV8 Actually, that property should indeed be recognized by the stylelint extension (see here:  https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration).

Comment: where on that page do they talk about the VSC settings.json file to edit?

Comment: @rioV8 OK good catch.  Re-reading that page, there is no mention of settings.json (my mistake).  Instead, it seems to say I should add this line to package.json (see https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration#loading-the-configuration-object).  I did so (screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/UBCD4n6.jpg).  Now, the line is no longer dimmed, so thanks for that.  But, I still can't seem to violate any codes from that ruleset.  Thoughts on that?  I can troubleshoot that on my own I guess.  If you leave an actual answer here, I can mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: that file has no json format description so **every** property is accepted. from the page `Starting from the current working directory....`

Comment: @rioV8 OK got it.  So what are you trying to say?  Are you saying `package.json` is not the file in which I should add the `extends` line?  If not, which file do you think should contain that line?  The documentation indicates the `extends` line should be added to the, "...stylelint config..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening an issue in the relevant GitHub repo, I was able to understand the answer to my question.

**Short Answer**:  The code I was adding was incorrect.  I was adding:

```
extends": "C:/Users/snarl/.vscode/extensions/stylelint-config-wordpress",
```

when I should have been adding something more along the lines of this:

```
"stylelint.config": {
  "extends": "C:/Users/snarl/index.js"
},
```

**Long Answer**:  If anyone is really curious about how to get this ruleset working in VSCode, you can read [this issue](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/stylelint-config-wordpress/issues/239).